# Are underscores an appropriate replacement for spaces for file names and URL's?

Tags: formatting

I'm localizing a website and need to support Korean.  As I understand, Korean stands out from Chinese and Japanese in that spaces are used for separation.

Latin-based languages commonly use underscores (or dashes) as a replacement for spaces.  Is it also common for Korean file names and URL's to replace spaces with underscores?

Comment: It's worth noting that many Korean websites just use English words for filenames and URLs. Source code also usually uses English variable names too.

Comment: Yes, especially for variable names. Using anything other than English alphabet for variable names is basically asking for trouble. :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think underscores are OK.

These days, all modern operating systems support filenames with spaces, so people frequently use Korean filenames with spaces in it, such as "6월 결산 보고서.xls" or something like that.

But in cases when space is problematic for some reason, "_" seems like a natural choice to me.

Comment: I just noticed that Korean Wikipedia does this. One problem is that many URL parsers can't handle the full URL because it contains Hangul. For example, send such a URL in a text message, but the recipient can't click on it because the app doesn't detect the full URL. Yes, this is a bug in the parser, but it's a pretty common one.